# Get async data with react redux probem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, axios

I had problem when I want to use some data (but the array is empty and the redux has the informations) I think it's an async problem. 
First I fetched my data in

```
  componentDidMount() {
     this.props.getFaq();
  }
```

and I want the result to map it.

for fetching the data first I used this code

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_FAQ, GET_ERRORS } from "./types";
export const getFaq = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get("/faqs")
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_FAQ,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err
      })
    );
};
```

then I changed it to

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_FAQ, GET_ERRORS } from "./types";
export const getFaq = () => async dispatch => {
  const payload = await getData();
  dispatch({
    type: GET_FAQ,
    payload
  });
};

async function getData() {
  const result = await axios("/faqs");
  console.log(result.data);
  return await result.data;
}
```

but the data is still empty when I console log it

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk in your redux store?

Comment: yes am using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly using axios.
Try to use

```
axios.get('/faqs');
```

or

```
const config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: '/faqs',
};
axios(config);
```